# enforce file casing via pre-commit hook

Tags: git, pre-commit.com

I would like to enforce lower-case – and possibly snake_case – file names throughout a git repo, ideally via a pre-commit hook. Alas, Google comes up empty for this particular use case; [`check-case-conflict`](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks#check-case-conflict) isn't quite what I'm looking for. Does any such thing exist?

Comment: Note that you also need to run this check in CI, since [pre-commit hooks can be trivially bypassed](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#restrict-with-hooks).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the easiest way to do this is via a [`language: fail`](https://pre-commit.com/#fail) hook

something like this:

```yaml
repos:
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    -   id: lower-case-only
        name: lower case only
        entry: filenames must be lower-case or lower_case only
        language: fail
        files: '[^a-z0-9._/-]'
```

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Comment: I think the `files` argument needs to be quoted?

Comment: yeah probably -- I wrote it on my phone and didn't test it

Comment: Note that this doesn't prevent renaming existing files: `git mv lowercase UPPERCASE && git commit` will succeed

Comment: @JaapJorisVens you're mistaken